# How to get the number of rows inserted using BigQuery Streaming

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am reading data from a CSV file, inserting the data to a Big Query table using insertAll() method from Streaming Insert as shown below:

```
InsertAllResponse response = dfsf.insertAll(InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId).setRows(rows).build());
```

**rows** here is an Iterable declared like this:

```
Iterable<InsertAllRequest.RowToInsert> rows
```

Now, I am actually batching the rows to insert into a size of 500 as suggested here - [link to suggestion](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2424#issuecomment-332609350)

After all the data has been inserted, how do I count the total number of rows that were inserted?
I want to find that out and log it to log4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done one of two ways

1. The BigQuery Jobs API via the getQueryResults
   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults
2. Cloud Logging, the output you want in the tableDataChange field.

Here is a sample output:

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {},
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "service_account"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "2600:1900:2000:1b:400::27",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "gl-python/3.7.1 grpc/1.22.0 gax/1.14.2 gapic/1.12.1 gccl/1.12.1,gzip(gfe)"
    },
    "serviceName": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/project_id/datasets/dataset/tables/table",
        "permission": "bigquery.tables.updateData",
        "granted": true
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/project_id/datasets/dataset/tables/table",
    "metadata": {
      "tableDataChange": {
        "deletedRowsCount": "2",
        "insertedRowsCount": "2",
        "reason": "QUERY",
        "jobName": "projects/PRJOECT_ID/jobs/85f19bdd-aff5-4abe-9283-9f0bc9ed3ce8"
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "7x7ye390qm",
  "resource": {
    "type": "bigquery_dataset",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "PRJOECT_ID",
      "dataset_id": "dataset-id"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-10-26T07:00:22.960735Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/PRJOECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-10-26T07:00:23.763159336Z"
}
```